How to calculate the autocorrelation function by when power spectral density is given
Is there a way to calculate the autocorrelation function based on power spectral density? I know that autocorrelation and Energy spectral density are Fourier transform pairs. As far as I know, there isn't such relation between autocorrelation and power spectral density.


"As far as I know, there isn't such relation between autocorrelation and power spectral density."  It is exactly the same as the relationship between the autocorrelation function of an energy signal and the energy spectral density, which you know: Fourier transform pair.

Look into the Wiener-Khinchin theorem.
